# In Sitecore Personalize, what are decision models? and how can I use a decision model?

Tags: personalization, decisioning, sitecore-personalize

I know that decisioning is a rule based engine for personalisation, but how can this actually be used in an experiment or experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decision model can be used with any Full Stack Interactive, Full Stack Triggered and `Web Experiences/Experiments`.

**Web Experiences/Experiments**

1. In the Build Section add your decision model in the Decisioning Section
2. In your variant open Advanced Edit to edit the `HTML`, `JavaScript` and `CSS`
3. In the `API` tab, add the data in `JSON` that you want to use in your Web Experience/Web Experiment. To add data from your decision model into your payload either use:

   - Snippets, for details see:
     https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/use-freemarker-snippets-in-an-api-response-for-a-web-experiment.html
   - Data Selector, For details see:
     https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/use-dynamic-decision-model-data-in-the-api-response.html
4. In the JavaScript or HTML tab, use the data you have returned in the API tab in the design of your Web Experience/Experiment. For details see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/using-custom-code-in-a-web-experiment-variant.html

Note: When updating the `API` tab, the output must be valid `JSON`.

**Full Stack Experiences/Experiments**

1. In the Build Section add your decision model in the Decisioning Section
2. Open your `personalisation` variant, add the data in `JSON` that you want to use in your `Web Experience/Web Experiment`. To add data from your decision model into your payload either use :

   - Snippets, for details see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/use-freemarker-snippets-in-an-api-response-for-an-interactive-experiment.html
   - Data Selector, For details see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/use-dynamic-decision-model-data-in-the-api-response-for-an-interactive-experiment-648890.html

Note: When updating the `API` tab, the output must be valid `JSON`.